# How to open file dialog box on asp

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am creating a web application (ASP). How to open file dialog box when the user clicks a button. I know there is a fileupload control in asp but I want to open file dialog on a simple button.

Comment: try this,http://forums.asp.net/t/1362059.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this example that will help you

```
<script runat="server">

    void SubmitButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
       if (File1.PostedFile != null) {
          try {
             File1.PostedFile.SaveAs("C:\\Uploads\\uploadedfile.txt");
             Span1.InnerHtml = "Upload Successful!";
          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
             Span1.InnerHtml = "Error saving file <b>C:\\" +
                File1.Value + "</b><br>" + ex.ToString();
          }
       }
    }

</script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
        <input id="File1" type="file" runat="Server" />
        <p>
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Upload File" 
             runat="Server" onserverclick="SubmitButton_Click" />
        </p>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using

```
 <input type="file"  id="fileLoader" name="files" title="Load File" ...
```

The usual trick is to make it invisible, and on clicking some visible artifact (styled link, image, button... whatever) simulate a click on fileLoader:

```
 $("#fileLoader").click();
```